# Connection Refused in pythonAnwhere

Tags: https, pythonanywhere, connection-refused

Uing BAsh console i installed Steem Module for Python3.6
and everything seems right but when i try to run my python script in Pythonanywhere it says there is problem connecting with api.steemit.com
but the script works fine in my PC. 
code 
    `import steem
    from steem import Steem
    s=Steem()
    s.get_account_history(your_ac, index_from=-1, limit=12)`
log is here. Is there any way to solve this issue?

WARNING:root:Retry in 1s -- MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.steemit.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewC
onnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connectio
n refused',))
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=19, connect=None, read=None, redirect=0, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnect
ionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refu
sed',)': /

Answer (score 3):

External connections for free accounts on PythonAnywhere are passed through a proxy. The error you're getting looks like the library you're using is not using the proxy. Check the docs for the library to see how to configure it to use a proxy. If it does not support it, contact the authors to see if they can add support for proxies.